# Java - Printing all pages from a Book

Tags: java, printing

I'm trying to print a Java Book but when I do only the first page of the book is being printed. I checked the number of pages in the Book and it is indeed the correct number of pages. The problem occurs when I try to print all of the pages. Below is the relevant snippets of code from my program.

I've never really done printing in Java before so I could be missing something obvious...

Thanks for any help!

```
 Book nb = new Book();

        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            String someString;
            ...
            JTextArea ta = new JTextArea();
            ta.setText(somestring);
            nb.append(ta.getPrintable(null, null), new PageFormat());
        }

        PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
        job.setPageable(nb);
        PrintRequestAttributeSet pras = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();

        boolean ok = job.printDialog(pras);

        if (ok) {
            try {
                job.print();
            } 
            catch (PrinterException ex) {}
        } 

        else {}
```

Comment: Java doesn't have a `Book` class unless you defined it, in which case you're not giving enough details.

Comment: I'm looking at this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/print/Book.html

Comment: Well I'll be. FYI AWT is extremely deprecated.

Comment: Then is there a straight forward viable alternative to what I'm trying to do?

Comment: AWT is certainly not deprecated. Did you ever find the solution to this  ? I have run against the exact same problem.